# Google API AutoComplete

Tags: swift, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I am trying to implement an autocomplete feature within my app.

I have set up a view controller with a button and added the code below.

However I keep getting the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'selectAddress' to type 'GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate?'

on this line:

> autocompleteController.delegate = self

Does anyone know why this is?

```html
import Foundation
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class selectAddress: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    // Present the Autocomplete view controller when the button is pressed.
    @IBAction func autocompleteClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.delegate = self
        self.present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

    // Handle the user's selection.
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
        print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // User canceled the operation.
    func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    func viewController(viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController!, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: NSError!) {
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.description)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the delegate to `self`, which is a class of type `selectAddress`, but the extension you have that conforms to the `GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate` protocol is of type `ViewController`.  If you change that to `extension selectAddress: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate` you'll be set.

Comment: Thank you, that's spot on 